# Does the audacity software have global shortcuts?

Tags: audacity

Is it possible to record/stop/play in Audacity without having focus on the Audacity window? I.e. global shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audacity does not support global hotkeys, so you need to use a third-party
tool.
The one I'll be using is the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following AutoHotkey script will map the following hotkeys:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, standing for Play,
  to <kbd>Space</kbd> for windows belonging to the process `audacity.exe`
- The <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hotkey, for Stop, will do the same mapping
  and is only added here for clarity
- The <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> hotkey, for Record, will map to the
  <kbd>R</kbd> key.

This is the AutoHotkey script:

```
#r::   ;record
  if WinExist("ahk_exe audacity.exe")
    ControlSend, , r, ahk_exe audacity.exe
  return

#s::   ;stop
#p::   ;play
  if WinExist("ahk_exe audacity.exe")
    ControlSend, , {Space}, ahk_exe audacity.exe
  return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: It's perfect, just what I was looking for! Thank you!